# What is the equivalent of DWORD in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, buffer, dword

I'm trying to rewrite a protocol in NodeJS from documentation written for C#.

I'm reading from an index file and here's the description of how the buffer is laid out.

[image]
[image]

From what I've read, `DWORD` is just a 32 bit unsigned integer. However, whenever I read the length bytes with `indexFileBuffer.readUInt32BE(offset)` I get a much longer length than expected.

Apparently `readUInt32BE()` is not the equivalent of `dword` or `dword` must be handled differently based on some criteria.

Any insight into how to properly calculate the value would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper functions to get a DWORD (unsigned 32 bit integer) from a buffer are either:

```
buf.readUInt32BE(offset)
```

or

```
buf.readUInt32LE(offset)
```

You do need to know whether your data is little endian or big endian byte ordering in order to select the right option of the two.

---

If you're using this and it isn't getting you the value you expect, then one of three things must be going on:

1. The data you expect to be in the buffer isn't what is there
2. You aren't using the right "endian" version
3. Your offset into the buffer where you're reading isn't correct

FYI, Intel uses little endian byte ordering, ARM uses big endian.  More on "endinan-ness" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. Everything is big endian according to the docs I've been reading. I'm 90% sure it will boil down to #3 now that you've confirmed that `readUInt32BE()` is the appropriate way to read the data _or_ the value acquired needs to be passed as another type during lookup since the number of bytes pulled by this length is far too many.